# error loading python opencv in windows

Tags: python, c++, python-2.7, opencv, numpy

I wish to load my opencv into python.
I followed this tutorial.

http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_setup/py_setup_in_windows/py_setup_in_windows.html

To set up my python.

However in the IDLE I encounter this error when I type import cv2
The cv2.pyd is already in the designated folder.

RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 9 but this version of numpy is 7

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
    import cv2
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import

I am using OPENCV 3.0.0 and python 2.7

Help please thank you.

Comment: Your OpenCV was compiled with a newer NumPy version than the one on your system. It seems you have NumPy 1.6 on your system, and your OpenCV was put together with 1.8 or 1.9. Update your system's NumPy to one of these newer versions and you should be ready to go.